# Backbone app (w. require & cordova) iphone emulation vs device

Tags: iphone, cordova, backbone.js, require

I have a backbone app running with require and cordova. It runs perfectly in the browser and when emulating through xcode on all devices. But for whatever reason when I attempt to run it through the device (iphone 5) it starts up but never runs, instead only giving me a blank white screen. I have attempted to console log using cordova's console logging plugin which allows for console logs to be written to xcode's terminal, but it's consistency is shotty at best and i haven't gotten anything legitimate that could lead to a reason it runs on one but not the other.

Has anyone ever dealt with this? I know this is a very vague question, just trying to see if anyone has ever ran into the same issue more or less.

Here is the body of my index.html file...

```
  <body>
    <div id="container">loading...</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Then this hits my main file, I am changing background color as a way of debugging, I am unable to change the background color from this file but I am able to in app.js ...

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "js/",
paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.2',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-1.0.0-min',
    text: 'libs/require/text',
    templates: '../templates',
    router: 'router',
    app: 'app',
},

shim: {
    underscore: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    backbone: {
        deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
        exports: "Backbone"
    }
}
});

require(['app', 'router', 'models/SessionModel'], function(app, AppRouter, SessionModel) {

$('body').css('background-color', 'yellow');
document.addEventListener("deviceready", run, false);

function run() {
    app.router = new AppRouter();
    app.session = new SessionModel({});

    app.session.checkAuth({
        // Start the backbone routing once we have captured a user's auth status
        complete: function(){
            Backbone.history.start();
        }
    });
}
```

});

Then here is the very basic app file...

```
define([
"jquery",
"underscore",
"backbone"
],
function($, _, Backbone) {

    var app = {
};

return app;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting an error even before the Cordova console plugin is loaded.

Try the following: Paste an `alert` message *before* the `deviceReady` event is fired.

Start the App, attach the Safari remote debugger and dispose the `alert` message, now you can see all the console output from there on. Most likely you will find a requirejs or cordova error there.